# I am using ZBar Bar Code Reader and want to customize the camera view for android

Tags: android, zbar-sdk

I am using ZBar Bar Code Reader and want to customize the camera view for android.

How can I put my view on top of it (with a transparent box in the centre & 60% opaque area around ) for the camera? but ZBar API for Android is totally different and much smaller. Please get me a solution & will be thankful for that.

I have use the source of ZBar from https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/tree/master/android